# Post Author not displaying (AngularJS, $http, MongoDB) - Thinkster MEAN Stack Tutorial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am a beginner to MEAN Stack Web Development, and have been working through the [mean-stack-tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/). I have come upto the last section with authenticating users, and everything seems to work fine (there are no console errors anywhere, and full functionality) however, in my `MainCtrl` in the index.ejs file, the post.author expression is not evaluating even when I login and submit a post (instead the `ng-show="post.author"` prevents it from displaying).

**angularApp.js** - I have edited the posts.create function in `MainCtrl` here to include an author. `auth.currentUser()` does indeed evaluate correctly in this controller (tested with `console.log(auth.currentUser());` in the `$scope.incrementUpvotes` function in `MainCtrl`.)

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve: {
        postPromise: ['posts', function(posts) {
          return posts.getAll();
        }]
      }
    })

    .state('posts', {
        url: '/posts/{id}',
      templateUrl: '/posts.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl',
      resolve: {
        post: ['$stateParams', 'posts', function($stateParams, posts) {
          return posts.get($stateParams.id);
        }]
      }
    })

    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: '/login.html',
      controller: 'AuthCtrl',
      onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', function($state, auth){
        if(auth.isLoggedIn()){
          $state.go('home');
        }
      }]
    })

    .state('register', {
      url: '/register',
      templateUrl: '/register.html',
      controller: 'AuthCtrl',
      onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', function($state, auth){
        if(auth.isLoggedIn()){
          $state.go('home');
        }
      }]
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])

.factory('auth', ['$http', '$window', function($http, $window){
   var auth = {};

   auth.saveToken = function(token) {
    $window.localStorage['flapper-news-token'] = token;
   };

   auth.getToken = function (){
    return $window.localStorage['flapper-news-token'];
  };

  auth.isLoggedIn = function(){
    var token = auth.getToken();

    if(token){
      var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));

      return payload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  auth.currentUser = function(){
    if(auth.isLoggedIn()){
      var token = auth.getToken();
      var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));

      return payload.username;
    }
  };

  auth.register = function(user) {
    return $http.post('/register', user).success(function(data) {
      auth.saveToken(data.token);
    });
  };

  auth.logIn = function(user){
    return $http.post('/login', user).success(function(data){
      auth.saveToken(data.token);
    });
  };

  auth.logOut = function(){
    $window.localStorage.removeItem('flapper-news-token');
  };

  return auth;
}])

.controller('AuthCtrl', [
'$scope',
'$state',
'auth',
  function($scope, $state, auth){
      $scope.user = {};

      $scope.register = function(){
        auth.register($scope.user).error(function(error){
          $scope.error = error;
        }).then(function(){
          $state.go('home');
        });
      };

      $scope.logIn = function(){
        auth.logIn($scope.user).error(function(error){
          $scope.error = error;
        }).then(function(){
          $state.go('home');
          console.log(auth.currentUser());
        });
      };
}])

app.factory('posts', ['$http', 'auth', function($http, auth){
  var o = {
    posts: []
  };
   o.getAll = function() {
    return $http.get('/posts').success(function(data){
      angular.copy(data, o.posts);
    });
  };

  o.get = function(id) {
    return $http.get('/posts/' + id).then(function(res){
      return res.data;
    });
  };

  o.create = function(post) {
  return $http.post('/posts', post, {
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
  }).success(function(data){
    o.posts.push(data);
    });
  };

  o.upvote = function(post) {
  return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/upvote', null, {
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
    }).success(function(data){
      post.upvotes += 1;
    });
  };

  o.addComment = function(id, comment) {
    return $http.post('/posts/' + id + '/comments', comment, {
      headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
    });
  };

  o.upvoteComment = function(post, comment) {
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/comments/'+ comment._id + '/upvote', null, {
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
    }).success(function(data){
        comment.upvotes += 1;
      });
  };

  return o;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope', 'posts', 'auth',
function($scope, posts, auth){
  $scope.test = 'Hello world!';

  $scope.posts = posts.posts;

  $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;

    $scope.addPost = function() {

    if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }

        posts.create({
      title: $scope.title,
      author: auth.currentUser(),
      link: $scope.link,
      });
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.link = '';
  };

    $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
    posts.upvote(post);
    console.log(auth.currentUser())
  };

}])
app.controller('PostsCtrl', [
'$scope',
'$stateParams',
'posts',
'post',
'auth',
function($scope, $stateParams, posts, post, auth){

  $scope.post=post;
  $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;

  $scope.addComment = function(){
    if($scope.body === '') { return; }

    posts.addComment(post._id, {
      body: $scope.body,
      author: 'user',
    }).success(function(comment) {
      $scope.post.comments.push(comment);
    });
    }
    $scope.addUpvote = function(comment){
      posts.upvoteComment(post, comment);
    };

    $scope.body = '';
  }

])

.controller('NavCtrl', [
'$scope',
'auth',
function($scope, auth){
  $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;
  $scope.currentUser = auth.currentUser;
  $scope.logOut = auth.logOut;
}]);
```

**Posts.js** - I have edited the mongoose model here to include an author.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    link: String,
    author: String,
    upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
    comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

PostSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
    this.upvotes += 1;
    this.save(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var router = express.Router();
var auth = jwt({secret: 'SECRET', userProperty: 'payload'});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
  }

  var user = new User();

  user.username = req.body.username;

  user.setPassword(req.body.password)

  user.save(function (err){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()})
  });
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
  }

  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    if(user){
      return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json(info);
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});

router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
    Post.find(function(err, posts) {
        if (err) { return next(err);}

        res.json(posts);
    });


});

router.post('/posts', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var post = new Post(req.body);
  post.author = req.payload.username;

  post.save(function(err, post){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});

router.param('post', function(req,res,next,id) {
  var query = Post.findById(id);

  query.exec(function (err, post) {
    if (err) { return next(err);}
    if (!post) { return next(new Error('can\'t find post')); }

    req.post = post;
    return next();
  });
});

router.param('comment', function(req,res,next,id) {
  var query = Comment.findById(id);

  query.exec(function (err, comment) {
    if (err) { return next(err);}
    if (!comment) { return next(new Error('can\'t find comment')); }

    req.comment = comment;
    return next();
  });
});

router.get('/posts/:post', function(req,res) {
  req.post.populate('comments', function(err,post) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});

router.put('/posts/:post/upvote', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.upvote(function(err, post){
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});

router.post('/posts/:post/comments', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var comment = new Comment(req.body);
  comment.post = req.post;
  comment.author = req.payload.username;

  comment.save(function(err, comment){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    req.post.comments.push(comment);
    req.post.save(function(err, post) {
      if(err){ return next(err); }

      res.json(comment);
    });
  });
});

router.put('/posts/:post/comments/:comment/upvote', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  req.comment.upvote(function(err, comment){
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(comment);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**index.ejs**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Flapper News</title>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
  <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default pull-right" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li ng-show="isLoggedIn()"><a>{{ currentUser() }}</a></li>
      <li ng-show="isLoggedIn()"><a href="" ng-click="logOut()">Log Out</a></li>
      <li ng-hide="isLoggedIn()"><a href="/#/login">Log In</a></li>
      <li ng-hide="isLoggedIn()"><a href="/#/register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>      

      <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">

      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Flapper News</h1>
      </div>

      <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
          ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
        {{post.upvotes}}
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
          <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
            {{post.title}}
          </a>
          <span ng-hide="post.link">
            {{post.title}}
          </span>
          <span ng-show="post.author">
            posted by <a>{{post.author}}</a> |
          </span>
        </span>
        <span>
            <a href="#/posts/{{post._id}}">Comments</a>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div ng-hide="isLoggedIn()">
        <h3>You need to <a href="/#/login">Log In</a> or <a href="/#/register">Register</a> before you can add a post.</h3>
      </div>

      <form ng-submit="addPost()" ng-show="isLoggedIn()" style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Title"
            ng-model="title"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Link"
          ng-model="link"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
      </form>

    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3>
            <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
                {{post.title}}
            </a>
            <span ng-hide="post.link">
                {{post.title}}
            </span>
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="addUpvote(comment)"></span>
                {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
            <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
                {{comment.body}}
            </span>
        </div>

      <div ng-hide="isLoggedIn()">
        <h3>You need to <a href="/#/login">Log In</a> or <a href="/#/register">Register</a> before you can comment.</h3>
      </div>

        <form ng-submit="addComment()" ng-show="isLoggedIn()" style="margin-top:30px;">
            <h3>Add a new comment</h3>

            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="body"></input>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
        </form>
    </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/register.html">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger row">
      <span>{{ error.message }}</span>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="register()"
      style="margin-top:30px;">
      <h3>Register</h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Username"
        ng-model="user.username"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Password"
        ng-model="user.password"></input>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    </form>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/login.html">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger row">
      <span>{{ error.message }}</span>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="logIn()"
      style="margin-top:30px;">
      <h3>Log In</h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Username"
        ng-model="user.username"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Password"
        ng-model="user.password"></input>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
    </form>
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The tutorial instructs to not include post.author in the posts.create function in `MainCtrl`, and does not update the mongoose model either. Under this setup, the `{{post.author}}` does not display either.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Edit: This is also not a browser caching error.

Answer (score 0):

If the post.author is the only field not displaying then I believe the problem is that you are not storing the author field correctly in the Post model in mongoDB, you could be storing an undefined value.

This might be because the `req.payload.username` might be evaluating to undefined because your jwt is not being decoded properly Instead of

```
router.post('/posts', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var post = new Post(req.body);
  post.author = req.payload.username;

  post.save(function(err, post){
```

try

```
router.post('/posts', auth, function(req, res, next) {
      var post = new Post(req.body);

      post.save(function(err, post){
```

your `req.body` already has the `username` property attached to it from the 
`o.create` in your `posts` factory. There is no point in reassigning it. 
also I completed the tutorial and have the author property working correctly, if you feel inclined you can look at my [github](https://github.com/udaiveerS/node-projects) in flapper folder.